# How to add index on ListField with mongoengine in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I want to add index on ListField.Here is my code:

```py
class Post(Document):

    meta = {"indexs":"testcomments.comment_id"}

    _id = StringField()
    txt = StringField()
    testcomments = EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment)
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))

class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):

    comment = StringField()
    comment_id = StringField()
    ...

...
```

I know how to add index on EmbeddedDocumentField (`meta = {"indexs":"testcomments.comment_id"}`),but how to add index on comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would work the same way for the list, thus

```
meta = {
"indexes": [
    "testcomments.comment_id",
    "comments.comment_id",    # or simply 'comments' if you want a multikey index
    ]
}
```

Note that you can check the indexes being created with

```
col = Page._get_collection()
c.index_information()
```

If you use the dict form to define indexes e.g: `meta = {'indexes': [{'fields': ['comments.comment_id']}}`, you can have more granularity on the index definition (and syntax closer to pymongo/mongodb)